# max_allowed_packets and MySQL server has gone away issues

Tags: mysql, server

I have a website with so many orders and products. Database size is around 4GB. I'm having a problem with mysql server I get this error

```
ERROR - 2017-04-26 17:24:35 --> Severity: Warning --> Error while sending QUERY packet. 
PID=742154 /home/like4car/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php 264
```

while the max_allowed_packets = 1000000000

In addition I get this error a lot on the new server and it causes many problems while these queries didn't cause such problems on the old server

```
Query error: MySQL server has gone away - Invalid query
```

So how to solve these issues according to these configurations

[image: Configuration]

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for your error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html)?

Comment: changed max_allowed_packets to 1024MB and still getting Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=878149 (this is the last error)